# Deno oak compatible types for request and response

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno, oak

I have been playing with Deno Oak. Looked at some of the basic routing examples and none of them are using types for request or response.

```
router
  .post("/api/v1/products", addProduct)


const addProduct = async (
  { request, response }: {
    request: any;
    response: any;
  },
) => {
  const body = await request.body();

  if (!body.value) {
    response.status = 404;
    response.body = {
      success: false,
      msg: "No data",
    };
  }
```

In above example, request and response is of `any` type. I tried to replace it with following types which are not compatible for body?

```
import { ServerRequest, ServerResponse } from "http://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
```

I'll appreciate if someone can point me to a relevant example or shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServerRequest` & `ServerResponse` are types used by Deno net. Oak uses `Request` & `Response`

```
const addProduct = async (
  { request, response }: {
    request: Request;
    response: Response;
  },
)
```

You can see that Oak `Response`, has a method [`toServerResponse`](https://github.com/oakserver/oak/blob/5f48c67214e5892e82a830347d8b6d9318557d32/response.ts#L247) that converts from Oak's Response to Deno net ServerResponse.

```js
/** Take this response and convert it to the response used by the Deno net
   * server.  Calling this will set the response to not be writable.
   * 
   * Most users will have no need to call this method. */
  async toServerResponse(): Promise<ServerResponse> {
```